# When working with NBTs in commands, what data type is assumed when values don't have a letter suffix?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Let's say you want to summon a sheep that glows. You'd probably go for `/summon minecraft:sheep ~ ~ ~ {Glowing:1b}`. And hey-ho, it works as expected. Glowing sheep.

Then to screw around some more and find out about data types, you try for `{Glowing:2b}`. The sheep still glows, so like other languages booleans actually work more like `0` and `not 0`. So for further screwing around—ahem, *'testing'*—you change `2b` to `2`. No change. So the game works with straight integers when it's expecting bytes. What if we exceed the range of a byte?

`{Glowing:127}`, glowing sheep. `{Glowing:128}`... still a glowing sheep? The number doesn't end up wrapping around to 0 until `256`. Forcing it into a byte, it wraps to 0 at `128b` and `-129b`. Further testing with coloured sheep confirms the unmarked number is unsigned.

The page on this on the [Official Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format) doesn't show any unsigned data types. Does anyone have some insight?

Comment: Nice, questions like these are why I follow the "minecraft" tag and endure all the bad questions in between. Also, I wanted to give a main source (apart from "my general game knowledge and a bit of trial and error") in the answer, but it's exactly the wiki page that you already linked. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When entering NBT, the provided data type mostly doesn't matter. It gets converted to the correct type for that field automatically.

Regular numbers become `int`s, so entering e.g. 3000000000 results in the value overflowing and becoming negative, even if it then gets converted to a `long`.

Numbers with decimal points become `double`s, including `.0` and `0.`.

Just a `.` seems to be accepted as a number, but I wasn't able to figure out what type. It plays along with other numbers labeled "`i`", but that shouldn't be a number suffix. Strange.

In arrays (like `Motion`) only one number type is accepted, even if they are compatible for conversion. So `[1.0,2.,3d]` is accepted, but `[0.0,0.0,0.0f]` is not.

Apparently arrays don't convert from whole number types to floating point types. Summoning an entity with `Motion:[1,0,0]` does not give it motion.

---

The remaining types are trivial: Array, compound and string. They don't have type suffixes.

---

Now to the other side of things: When **reading** NBT, you do have to match the correct type. Because your input gets implicitly converted to `int` or `double` if you provide no format suffix and only then it's compared with the existing NBT, it often fails.
So even if you summon an entity with `Motion[0.0f,0.0f,0.0f]`, you still can't test for it with `Motion[0.0f,0.0f,0.0f]`, you need `Motion[0.0d,0.0d,0.0d]`.

Comment: When appying an integer to a TAG_Byte, why is the overflow cap at 256?

Comment: Because it can overflow again when being converted to a byte. Byte=8 bit=256 combinations

Comment: I've greatly progressed in my computer science education since posting this question, and I'd like to add on something that would have been useful back in January.

A byte, as Fabian says, can count to decimal 256. The breadth of my experience was mostly C programming, a language in which compilers assume integers of all sizes are _signed_ unless otherwise stated, hence why 127+1 would become -128. Signed integers utilise numbers 128–255 to represent negative numbers.

Simply put, a sheep's `{Glowing}` tag can be 255 because it's assumed to be an _unsigned_ byte, which can count that high.