# How do I send a custom Tellraw message based on the player in a certain location in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a Minecraft map I'm making, I want public messages to be sent when a player steps on a certain pressure plate or walks through a specific door, and for the message to say who exactly did it. Also, I want it to be able to handle multiple players in the same spot and does its job respectively.

For example, if a person walks into a door, it says,

> "**their username** has walked through the door."

I'm currently using

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"","color":"yellow","extra":[{"selector":"@p[distance=3]"},{"text":" has walked through the door."}]}
```

but it doesn't seem to work, and rather responds with,

> " has walked through the door."

Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between the single dot, double dot and triple dot operators in Minecraft commands](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/360777/what-is-the-difference-between-the-single-dot-double-dot-and-triple-dot-operato)

Comment: Try making the "@p[distance=..3]" instead of what it is right now. This should fix the problem with no targets being found but this command line alone won't making exactly what you want...

Comment: @BrunoRodrigues Please don't answer in comments.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 The answer to that question explains that " Example, this will only match someone who is exactly 0.5 blocks away from you, which is pretty much impossible to achieve with regular walking: @a[distance=0.5]". That is exactly the problem here, as pointed out in Bruno Rodrigues' comments. I don't see how that makes it not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Minecraft uses dots to specify **bigger than** and **smaller than** when using tags such as `distance=n`.

- 2 dots in front (`distance=..n`) stands for **smaller than n**.
- 2 dots at the end (`distance=n..`) stands for **bigger than n**.

Additionally, both terms can be used in one tag (e.g.: `distance=y..n` stands for **bigger than y and smaller than n**.).

To answer your question, change `distance=3` to `distance=..3`, problem solved.